# More optimised alternative to gdal.Translate to save WMS to TIFF

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, wms

I'm currently writing a plugin which at some point saves an image of dynamic extent and resolution from WMS as a TIFF. I'm using the following code to archieve this:

```py
ds=gdal.Translate(localrasterpath,"WMS:"+wms_url,height=height,width=width, projWin=[xMin,yMax,xMax,yMin])
ds=None
```

While this works, it takes a lot of time. It takes about 2.2 seconds to execute this line for a 2500x2500px image. This would be fine, if it wasn't used in a for-loop and thus executed 31 times (once for each layer in the wms) per run, totalling about 70 seconds.

Since this is like 90% of the time my plugin takes to run I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

For context, these are the steps in which I use the produced image:

```py
#binarize the image via numpy array                
im = np.array(Image.open(localrasterpath).convert('L'))
im_bin = (im < 250) * 255
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(im_bin)).save(binrasterpath)
del im, im_bin, ds
#re-georeference the image
src_ds = gdal.Open(binrasterpath)
src_ds.SetGeoTransform(gdal.Open(localrasterpath).GetGeoTransform())
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()
src_ds.SetProjection(dest_wkt)
```

If there was a way to open the WMS directly as a numpy array I'd be very happy, however I couldn't find anything myself.

Comment: How long does it take to read the image from WMS with plain http request? Is the problem that the WMS does not support TIFF as an output format and therefore you need to use GDAL.

Comment: why not request all the layers together in one hit

Comment: @IanTurton I need to create vectorlayers from the WMS. The features of said vectorlayers should know from which WMS Layer they were created. From what I've found the by far easiest (if not only) way to archieve this is to polygonize each layer individually.

I know WMS isn't supposed to be used this way, but it's the only data source available.

Comment: @user30184 Both creating+loading a raster layer from the wms and getting an image when accessed directly via the web browser take about 0.2 seconds each. Saving the image as a png, which is supported by the WMS, takes around 3 seconds per layer, so even worse than TIFF

Comment: And how long does it take if you have a 2500x2500 pixel png image on disk and convert it into TIFF with gdal_translate? What do you mean by "Saving the image as a png, which is supported by the WMS, takes around 3 seconds per layer"? How do you save the image? From browser window, with curl by using the same WMS GetMap request or how?

Comment: @user30184 By saving the image as a png I meant just using gdal_translate with an output path ending in .png instead of .tif as PNGs are actually supported according to the WMS capabilities. Converting locally saved PNGs to TIFFs with gdal_translate takes around 0.35 seconds each. So what takes so long is getting the data from the server and not the creation of a local file? Does that mean I can't optimise much on my end?

Comment: Have you measured how much time the steps in your code are using? Have you considered to use just gdal_translate with the WMS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html? The usage would be something like `gdal_translate -of GTiff -outsize 2500 2500 -projwin ulx uly lrx lry my_wms_config.xml my_output.tif`.